# Conditional "for" Loop/Stop repetition

Tags: python, for-loop

I have been learning the basics of python and have made a few projects with guided help from YouTube. As my first solo-project I wanted to make a clone of the game "Wordle", a game similar to hangman but it is 5-letter words only and you have to guess the correct position of the letter in the word (wordle) as well as the correct letter, unlike hangman.

I have managed to get a functional game but I'm having some problems when it comes to words with repeating letters such as sheep, steel, scene, trust, etc.

Here's what is output when the guessed word contains a repeating letter (SHEEP is the word the user is trying to guess in this example and is only shown for now to help me test my code) :

[image: Example of output]

I know why this happens, it is because the print is within a for loop, but do not know how to stop it from happening.

I also don't know why it only prints out that the letter repeats in position 3 instead of printing:

"The letter E repeats in position 3" and "The letter E repeats in position 4" considering the wordle is sheep (as seen at the top).

Here is the relevant bit of code:

**Where input is requested and turned into a list:**

```
user_input = input("Guess a 5-letter word: ").upper()
user_input_letters = list(user_input)
```

**Where input is processed:**

```
#Searches for matching letters between user_input and wordle
        for letter in user_input_letters:

            count = wordle_letters.count(letter)

            #If matching letters are found and only found once
            if letter in wordle_letters and count == 1:
                letter_pos_wordle = wordle_letters.index(letter)
                letter_pos_user_input = user_input.index(letter)
                
                #Checking if position of letter in user_input matches position of letter in wordle
                if letter_pos_user_input == letter_pos_wordle:
                    word_list[letter_pos_user_input] = letter

                else:
                    print("The letter", letter, "is in the word but not in position", letter_pos_user_input+1)
            
            #If matching letters are found and found more than once
            elif letter in wordle_letters and count > 1:
                letter_pos_wordle = wordle_letters.index(letter)
                print("The letter",letter,"repeats in position",letter_pos_wordle+1)

            #No matching letters found
            else:
                continue
```

The array "word_list" is just where I store correct letters that the user has guessed, it is defined above as:

```
word_list = ["-","-","-","-","-"]
```

Comment: Please trim the question down to *just* the *specific* issue you’re facing.  (Minimal reproducible example)

Comment: One thing to note: [str.index](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) returns the index where the substring is _first_ found in the string, which is where you get the same position each run for `wordle_letters.index(letter)`